# Delay in ReadFile while reading serial port

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm trying to understand, why my read function takes so much "extra" time(approx 60ms)? It must take approx 50 ms, but instead I spend in read function 130-140ms. At the picture(green - send, yellow - receive) I marked when `read(3)` called and when it's done. Everything works as expected but there is strange delay. Because port  baud rate is only 600 bit/s and communication is synchronous I can't blindly wait 60ms, it is very wasteful. Experiments with timeouts, buffer size, etc gives nothing. Is it possible to get rid of this delay in read function?

```
std::vector<byte> read(const size_t expected)
{
    std::vector<byte> buffer(expected, 0);
    DWORD totalReaded = 0, bytesReaded, dwEventMask;
    if (!SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR))
        throw std::runtime_error("SetCommMask failed.");

    if (!WaitCommEvent(hPort, &dwEventMask, NULL))
        throw std::runtime_error("WaitCommEvent failed.");

    do
    {
        if (ReadFile(hPort, &buffer[totalReaded], buffer.size() - totalReaded, &bytesReaded, nullptr))
        {
            totalReaded += bytesReaded;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::exception("ReadFile failed!");
        }
    } while (totalReaded < buffer.size());
    buffer.resize(totalReaded);
    return buffer;
}
```

Full program code: http://pastebin.com/iu1j8V0g

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using say `byte data[1024];` and `ReadFile(hPort, data, sizeof data, nullptr);`, `buffer.append(buffer.end(), &buffer[0], &buffer[bytesReaded]);` etc.?  It might be that function call overhead - repeated for every single byte - is slowing you down....

Comment: @Tony D, yes, nothing really changes.

Comment: This is entirely beyond the control of ReadFile or your program, you'll need to find a better device driver.  Which usually involves throwing away what you bought and shopping for something that doesn't cost less than 5 dollars.

Comment: Why are you reading 1 byte at a time when you know how many bytes you are expecting? You should pre-allocate the `vector` to that size and then call `ReadFile()` asking for the total number of bytes at one time.  If `ReadFile()` happens to return fewer bytes, then call it again for the remaining bytes at one time, and so on until all bytes have been read. There is no reason to read 1 byte at a time in this example. And don't forget to do error handling on `ReadFile()` (which is missing in the above code).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, I agree, there is no reason to read port byte by byte, but unfortunately changing function logic don't change delay =( I updated question with refactored read function.